# Where Device Farm puts the content of a zip archive with "extra data" on iOS?

Tags: ios, aws-device-farm

For our tasks, we need to put a folder with some content on a device before running an app.
For Android devices all seems to work fine, but for iOS it seems that content of a zip archive stored in place where our app didn't expect it. Where by default content of a zip archive will be extracted on iOS devices?
In my case, I need to put data to `Documents/myfolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS, Device Farm puts Extra Data that you upload with the ScheduleRun operation into the application's sandbox. From the [Device Farm FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/):

> Q: I’d like to supply media or other data for my app to consume. How
>   do I do that?
>
> You can provide a .zip archive up to 4 GB in size. On Android, it will
>   be extracted to the root of external memory; on iOS, to your app’s
>   sandbox. For Android expansion files (OBB), we will automatically
>   place the file into the location appropriate to the OS version. For
>   more information, see the Developer Guide.